# Using JSRuntime.InvokeAsync causes "Index was out of range" error on BlazorStrap Carousel

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-jsinterop

In my Blazor Server Application I have a page with a BlazorStrap Carousel and a button to download a zip file. The Carousel works fine and can loop through all of the images without issue until I click the button to download the zip file. The zip file downloads correctly but after that I get this error in the console:

> Error: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range.
> Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
> (Parameter 'index')    at
> System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index)    at
> BlazorStrap.BSCarouselBase.AnimationEnd(BSCarouselItemBase sender)
> at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task
> task)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task
> taskToHandle)

Html for my carousel and download files button:

```
<BlazorStrap.BSCarousel NumberOfItems="@slideshowImages.Count" style="width: 23vw;">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        @foreach (var item in slideshowImages)
        {
            <BlazorStrap.BSCarouselItem Src="@item.Source" Alt="@item.Alt" style="width: 100%;">
                @if (bShowImageTitle == true)
                {
                    <BlazorStrap.BSCarouselCaption CaptionText="@item.Caption.Split('.')[0]" />
                }
            </BlazorStrap.BSCarouselItem>
        }
    </div>
    <BlazorStrap.BSCarouselControl CarouselDirection="BlazorStrap.CarouselDirection.Previous" NumberOfItems="@slideshowImages.Count" />
    <BlazorStrap.BSCarouselControl CarouselDirection="BlazorStrap.CarouselDirection.Next" NumberOfItems="@slideshowImages.Count" />
</BlazorStrap.BSCarousel>

<button class="btn btn-primary bold" type="button" @onclick="(e => btnDownloadAllClick())">DOWNLOAD FILES</button>
```

Code for getting carousel items:

```
List<Slideshow> slideshowImages = new List<Slideshow>();

public class Slideshow
{
    public string Source { get; set; }
    public string Alt { get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; set; }
    public string Header { get; set; }
}

public int iImageCount;

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    //here i'm getting the images from a folder in azure storage, this works fine
    List<string> tempList = clsBlobService.ListBlobs(folderPath);

    foreach (var img in tempList)
        {
            Slideshow tempItem = new Slideshow
            {
                Source = rootPath + img,
                Alt = img.Split('/').Last(),
                Caption = img.Split('/').Last()
            };

            slideshowImages.Add(tempItem);
        }

        iImageCount = slideshowImages.Count;
}
```

Code for when the download files button is clicked:

```
public async void btnDownloadAllClick()
{   
    await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("open", "/Temp/MyZipFile.zip");
}
```

Edit: I forgot to add that my render-mode is Server and not ServerPrerendered.

Comment: Would you be able to post a reproducible set of code either here or on Github?  It might take some experimentation to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error happens `at BlazorStrap.BSCarouselBase.AnimationEnd()`.

But on GitHub I can't find BSCarouselBase and [the record](https://github.com/chanan/BlazorStrap/issues/384) suggests your bug was fixed.

So, update your package(s).

Comment: The error no longer occurs on the AnimationEnd() but is now occurring at BlazorStrap.BSCarousel.ResetTimer()

Comment: @SarahCox: Then update the question. Specify which versions (Blazor & BlazorStrap), include all relevant (async) code.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 
    @if (bShowImageTitle == true 
                && item.Caption.Split('.')!=null  
                   && item.Caption.Split('.').Length > 0  
        )
     {
      <BlazorStrap.BSCarouselCaption CaptionText="@item.Caption.Split('.')[0]" />
      }
```